# Nest Doorbell not ringing indoor chime

Tags: electrical, nest, doorbell

I recently picked up the doorbell from Nest, the Nest Hello and set it up. One issue that I'm running into is what wires should be used when trying to make it work with the indoor chime.

The instructions from Nest state that the front and trans wires are removed and attached to the Nest connector. The **Nest connector** then has two wires coming out that go to those respective spots.

What I found with my transformer is that I have two sets of wires for each the front and trans spots and I'm unsure which ones would be used. The setup reminds me of a parallel circuit from physics class but more than that, I have no idea.

Please see the images for clarification. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all of your nest apps on your phones/iPads are set the same. One of mine was set different (indoor chime off) and shut the chime down.

Answer (score 0):

If the existing setup was working correctly, I would keep it wired as it currently is.

To do so, you can remove both wires from 'Front', splice them together and insert them in to the Nest Connector's 'Front' input, and then connect the 'Front' Jumper from the Nest Connector to the 'Front' terminal on your chime.

Then do the same for the Trans terminal. The goal is to have the connector be attached to the terminals in the chime.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Originally the indoor doorbell chime rang, then it stopped ringing the day after install. I found that the reason was that the white Nest connector wires that I added in the chime we’re getting in the way of the electro mechanical solonoid. They were preventing the movement. Once I moved the wires out of the way it started ringing again.

One other thing- there is a setting called Indoor Chime On/Off. If Off, then the indoor chime won’t ring but the Nest doorbell itself will make a bell sound.